# IOS iRdesktop GPL stuck in Portrait mode?

Tags: ios, orientation, landscape, portrait

I'm stuck on an app I'm building and need a little advice. Can anyone help or point me to a good resource?

I downloaded the GPL version of iRdesktop (http://www.irdesktop.com/gpl/) and created my own RDP client, but the app is stuck in Portrait orientation mode only. Only the launch image is displayed in Landscape mode.

I've configured the project's General Settings and plist file to only use Landscape, as well as searched for every instance I found of (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation in the code and returned YES. Still no luck. I've only been able to get the navigation bar in Landscape mode, the content is still displayed in Portrait mode.

Any advice?

Thanks again, Chris